# Implement IF in MySQL SUM Timestamps difference

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that sum time difference I want it to set negative time difference to zero or neglect it.

```
SELECT 
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, GREATEST('2017-10-16 16:00:00',created_at),LEAST('2017-10-17 00:00:00',IFNULL(closed,NOW()))

                         )) AS totalWork, created_at, closed
         FROM cavity_actions WHERE  cavity_id = 52 AND action_id = 10 AND job_id = 42 GROUP BY created_at, closed
```

This query returns:

```
totalWork    created_at            closed
-12588       2017-10-07 21:12:48   2017-10-07 22:11:08
480          2017-10-07 22:17:45   NULL
```

I need to neglect the negative value or set it to zero.

I have tried to use the `totalWork` alias in the WHERE clause but Unknown column error is generated.

Is there any way that allows to set each `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` output in a variable then using it in IF clause?

I have tried :

```
SELECT 
        SUM(@td := TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, GREATEST('2017-10-16 16:00:00',created_at),LEAST('2017-10-17 00:00:00',IFNULL(closed,NOW()))

                         ) IF(td > 0,td,0)) AS totalWork, created_at, closed
         FROM cavity_actions WHERE cavity_id = 52 AND action_id = 10 AND job_id = 42 GROUP BY created_at, closed
```

But it returns error.

Comment: Use having clause to remove it. totalWork > 0;

Comment: Would `Having(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, GREATEST('2017-10-16 16:00:00',created_at),LEAST('2017-10-17 00:00:00',IFNULL(closed,NOW()))))) > 0` work?

Comment: @Fran placing having generates errors. However, Gordon solution seems to be perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `IF()` (or `CASE`, which is the ANSI standard).  You can use `GREATEST()`:

```
SELECT SUM(GREATEST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
                                  GREATEST('2017-10-16 16:00:00', created_at),
                                  LEAST('2017-10-17 00:00:00', COALESCE(closed, NOW()))

                                 ), 0
                   )
          ) AS totalWork,
       created_at, closed
FROM cavity_actions
WHERE cavity_id = 52 AND action_id = 10 AND job_id = 42
GROUP BY created_at, closed
```

Comment: But  why is COALESCE instead of IFNULL ?

Comment: @SaidbakR . . . `COALESCE()` is ANSI standard functionality available in all (real) databases.